# Argument Exception “Item with Same Key has already been added”

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I am receiving the error:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>         HResult=-2147024809
>         Message=An item with the same key has already been added.

When attempting to load a page in this application.  Visual Studio is pointing to this line:

```
_db.GroupProgramPlans.Select(x => new {Code = x.GroupCode, Name = x.Group}).Distinct().ForEach(x=> groups.Add(x.Code,x.Name));
```

as the line causing the error.  The table the code is querying does not have a PK.  I have run through the table looking for duplicate rows.  There are only about 30 rows in the table and while they have common column values, there are not any duplicate rows.  I have tried removing the .Distinct().  Not really sure what is causing the error and how it should be handled.  Below is the code.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var groups = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            _db.GroupProgramPlans.Select(x => new {Code = x.GroupCode, Name = x.Group}).Distinct().ForEach(x=> groups.Add(x.Code,x.Name));

            ViewBag.Groups = groups;

            return View(_db.DocumentTemplates.Where(x => x.Active == true));
        }
```

Comment: `Distinct` applies to your anonymous object not to the `GroupCode`. For anonymous objects: they are equal if **all properties** have the same value. Use *GroupBy* for `GroupCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something like this

```
var groups = _db.GroupProgramPlans
                .GroupBy(x=>x.GroupCode)
                .Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToDictionary(x=>x.GroupCode,x=>x.Group);
```